# Passing parameters to Laravel job is not working

Tags: laravel

I've read solutions to this problem before but it seems that I'm doing something else wrong and that's why I'm asking: Usually the solution is adding the parameters to the body of the class as well as the __construct method but even doing that it doesn't work.

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Mail\TasksFinished;

class SendMailFinished implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $tries = 3;

    protected $msg;

    protected $subj;

    protected $mailto;

    public function __construct($msg, $subj, $mailto)
    {
        //
        $this->msg = $msg;
        $this->subj = $subj;
        $this->mailto = $mailto;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        //Envia correo cuando termine cola.
        Mail::to($this->mailto)->queue(new TasksFinished($this->msg, $this->subj));
    }
```

I try to run this through a queue this way in tinker:

```
use App\Jobs\SendMailFinished;
$job = new SendMailFinished('Hola', 'Prueba', 'ffuentes@example.org');
$job->dispatch();
```

> TypeError: Too few arguments to function
>   App/Jobs/SendMailFinished::__construct(), 0 passed in
>   C:/laragon/www/reportes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bus/Dispatchable.php
>   on line 16 and exactly 3 expected

Why even after specifying all the parameters both in the class and during instantiation it still cannot see any parameters when dispatching. (I've tried making params public as well but it's the same thing).

Comment: Please mark your question as answered if any answer worked out for you.

Comment: I am facing the same issue on Laravel version 8.17.
Not working any solutions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you call `dispatch()` you should send the parameter there.

Try calling it statically

```php
SendMailFinished::dispatch('Hola', 'Prueba', 'ffuentes@example.org');
```

Answer (score 10):

There are 2 ways to pass parameters to a dispatching job in laravel.
First is simply call `dispatch` or `dispatchNow` as per requirement on your Job class like calling a static method on class:

```
YourJob::dispatch(argument1, argument2, argument3);
```

Second is simply pass arguments while creating an instance/object of Job class then pass object to dispatch method(always available in controller) like:

```
$this->dispatch(new YourJob(argument1, argument2, argument3));
```

The arguments will be available in the constructor, can you assign them to class local variable properties and use anywhere in Job class.

Comment: Funny. Your comment has been very useful! I was really struggling with an issue where a Job being called from a artisan command failed to execute. (supposed to write some blank records to DB when a cron runs every week, but for the last couple of months it sometimes misfired or created double entries.) I put some code in the function __construct of the Job to write something to a file when it loads, and sure enough it works, but for some reason none of the code in the handle() function executed. After reading this answer, I thought, let me try dispatchnow, instead of dispatch. IT WORKED!