# Laravel queue job send request

Tags: php, laravel, queue

In my controller I dispatch all request to my job

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   ClientJob::dispatch($request->all());
}
```

And How I can get my requests inside handle my job

```
 public function handle()
 {
    $request;
 }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing parameters to Laravel job is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57978163/passing-parameters-to-laravel-job-is-not-working)

Comment: Yes it is beneficial for me , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the parameter un the construct method

```
protected $request;

public function __construct($request)
{
    $this->request = YourData;
}

public function handle()
{
    $this->request;
}
```